# Is anything known about science fiction illustrator Martin Key?

Tags: art, cover-art

Martin Key is listed as the illustrator in the debut issue of *If* magazine, March 1952. The cover illustration is this:

[image: *If* cover, March 1952]

Wikipedia has nothing. Amazon has nothing (not surprising, maybe 1 in 20 of the classic pulp illustrators will have an art book). I have no proof the man ever existed, it was perhaps a pen name.

I have went through almost all issues of this magazine title, and it seems he had never done another cover for it. Though, in that era, there were three or four dozen science fiction magazines, and a thriving paperback novel market.

I would like any details about this artist that may be available, even just other titles that he provided artwork/illustrations for.

Comment: Neither my 1979 or 1993 paper editions of "The Science Fiction Encyclopedia" have an entry for him, nor does the online version.

Comment: This question is too broad. For example, an answer detailing human physiology for fit under "any details about this artist that may be available". Please consider editing your question to zero on on what specifically you are interested in: information about his artistic career? Autobiography? Biographics of his personal life (e.g., geography, religious affiliation, family, etc.)?

Comment: @JohnO Please [be nice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/conduct). It's fine to defend your question, but you can do so without making personal attacks on close-voters.